# The range of the controllability matrix

Tags: control-theory

Consider a matrix $M$, the range of $M$, denoted by $R(M)$:

$R(M) = \{b | b = Mx\}.$

Now, consider the controllability matrix $$C = \begin{bmatrix}B&AB & \dots& A^{n-1}B\end{bmatrix}=\\= \begin{bmatrix}I& A&\dots&A^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}B$$

How to understand the columns of $B$ belongs to $R(C)$?
I hope a more intuitive way to see this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: It helps to know that $Cx$ is a linear combination of the columns of $C$.  More explicitly, if the $i$th component of $x$ is $x_i$ and the $i$th column of $C$ is $c_i$, then $Cx = \sum_i x_i c_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of a matrix is the span of the column vectors of that matrix. The columns of $B$ are also columns of $C$ by definition, so they are in $R(C)$.